# How can I compute the sum and the average of the given array?

Tags: java, arrays

When I run the code, it always stops when the inputted element is found or not found, and the rest of the code where I have to compute the average and the sum seems not to work.
I do not know what seems to be wrong since I am an absolute beginner at coding.

The code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of element in the array:");
        int The_scan = sc.nextInt();
        int count_index,sum;
        count_index = 0;
        sum = 0;
        float average = 0;
        int[] inputted_array = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            inputted_array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The elements are: "+ Arrays.toString(inputted_array));
        System.out.print("What is the element to be search: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < The_scan; i++ ){
            if(inputted_array[i] == search) {
                System.out.println("Element " + search + " is found in index " + i + '.');
                count_index++
            }
        }
        if(count_index == 0){
            System.out.println("Element "+search+" not found");
        }
        for (int i =0; i <inputted_array.length ;i++ ){
            sum = sum + inputted_array[i];
            System.out.println("The sum value of the elements is:" + sum);
        }
        average = sum/ inputted_array.length;
        System.out.println("The average value of the elements is:" + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: for one, this: System.out.println("The sum value of the elements is:" + sum); should be after the loop, not in it. What exactly is going wrong with your code? have you debugged your code to see what it does?

Comment: In the code it seems like count_index is not declared.

Comment: @tommueller it is

Comment: @nights I just tried your code here. a few remarks: you'll need to add an ';' after the line count_index++ . Besides that, your code works without the issues you mentioned

Comment: one thing that's also off: when reading the data, you have a hardcoded length of 5, where you should use the value of The_scan

Comment: `Arrays.stream(inputted_array).summaryStatistics()` will actually do all the sum and average work for you - but if this is an assignment that is probably not what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There were couple of errors in your code, might be that is the reason of you code not running properly. And I also saw that you gave an option to the user to choose the length of the array but you did not use the value they entered at all.

Here are some fixes and now it works fine.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arraySumAndAvg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of element in the array:");
        int The_scan = sc.nextInt();
        int count_index,sum;
        count_index = 0;
        sum = 0;
        float average = 0;
        int[] inputted_array = new int[The_scan];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < The_scan ; i++){
            inputted_array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The elements are: "+ Arrays.toString(inputted_array));
        System.out.print("What is the element to be search: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < The_scan; i++ ){
            if(inputted_array[i] == search) {
                System.out.println("Element " + search + " is found in index " + i + '.');
                count_index ++;
            }
        }
        if(count_index == 0){
            System.out.println("Element "+search+" not found");
        }
        for (int i =0; i <inputted_array.length ;i++ ){
            sum = sum + inputted_array[i];
            
        }
System.out.println("The sum value of the elements is:" + sum);
        average = sum/ inputted_array.length;
        System.out.println("The average value of the elements is:" + average);
    }
}
```

**What I changed.**

I updated the code so that the inputted_array can now store the numbers up to which the user defines rather than only 5 numbers.

**previously**

```
int[] inputted_array = new int[5];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    // statements.
}
```

**Now**

```
int The_scan = sc.nextInt();

int[] inputted_array = new int[The_scan];
for (int i = 0 ; i < The_scan; i++){
    // statements.
}
```

and I also fixed some syntax errors.

Comment: actually, that value was used in the original code, just not everywhere.

It might be easier for the OP to understand if you explained what you changed and why you changed it

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion i will make sure to update my answer

Comment: I  put the System.out.println("The sum value of the elements is:" + sum); outside of the loop and it works fine. Thank you to everyone who helped.